# Como solucionar bug con carrusel de imagenes en JavaScrip?

Tags: javascript, html, css

estuve intentando crear un carrusel de imágenes aplicándole al carrusel un scrollLeft con JavaScript, y funciono perfectamente. El problema esta en que si intentas darle varios clicks a la flecha que cambia de imagen, ya sea hacia adelante o hacia atrás, puedes observar un pequeño bug en el cual se muestra en la pantalla la mitad de una imagen y la mitad de la imagen que le sigue o le antecede. Agradecería mucho si alguien me puede ayudar con este problema, muchas gracias!

codigo HTML

```
 <main>
    <div class="carousel-container">
        <button class="before" id="before" role="button"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i></button>

        <div class="carousel" id="carousel">
            <div class="image image1">
                <img src="images/image-product-1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="image image2">
                <img src="images/image-product-2.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="image image3">
                <img src="images/image-product-3.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="image image4">
                <img src="images/image-product-4.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>

        <button class="next" id="next" role="button"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i></button>
    </div>
</main>
```

Codigo CSS

```
    *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.carousel-container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 100vh;
    button{
        border: none;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 40px 20px;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        transition: .3s all ease;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1000;
        &:hover{
            background: #000;
        }
    }
    .before{
        left: 0;
    }
    .next{
        right: 0;
    }
    .carousel{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        width:600px;
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
        .image{
            min-width: 100%;
            img{
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Codigo JavaScript

```
const before = document.getElementById("before");
const next = document.getElementById("next");
const carousel = document.getElementById("carousel");
const carouselImages = document.querySelectorAll(".image");
let contador = 0;

next.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
    let carouselWidth = carousel.clientWidth;
    carousel.scrollLeft += carouselWidth;
    if(contador < carouselImages.length){
        contador++;
    }
    if(contador == carouselImages.length){
        carousel.scrollLeft = carousel.clientWidth - (carouselImages.length * carousel.clientWidth);
        contador = 0;
    }
})

before.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    let carouselWidth = carousel.clientWidth;
    carousel.scrollLeft -= carouselWidth;
    if(contador > 1 ){
        contador--;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para el boton de la derecha, puedes calcular la diferencia que hay entre el scrollLeft que ya tienes mas el que le vas a sumar.

```
 const before = document.getElementById("before");
 const next = document.getElementById("next");
 const carousel = document.getElementById("carousel");
 const carouselImages = document.querySelectorAll(".image");
 let contador = 1;

 next.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      let carouselWidth = carousel.clientWidth;
      carousel.scrollLeft += (carouselWidth * contador ) - carousel.scrollLeft;
      if (contador == carouselImages.length) {
           carousel.scrollLeft = carousel.clientWidth - (carouselImages.length * carousel.clientWidth);
           contador = 1;
      }else
           contador++;
 })
```

Para no tener que hacer tanta validacion defino el contador en 1 como valor minimo por default. Y para el retorno creo que solo basta con checar cuanto scroll deberia de tener dependiendo del contador al que a cual deberia de ir, y quitarle el width actual

```
 before.addEventListener("click", () => {
      let carouselWidth = carousel.clientWidth;
      if (contador > 1) {
           contador--;
      } 
      carousel.scrollLeft = (carouselWidth * contador) - carouselWidth;
 })
```

Eso si, esto creo solo haria que si le diera dos clicks rapidos o tres se saltara esas dos o tres imagenes, no permaneceria en la siguiente.

Nos comentas si es lo que quieres o si te ayuda, saludos.

Comment: era exactamente lo que necesitaba, me fue de gran ayuda, muchas gracias!

Comment: @DanielAlves si esta respuesta soluciona tu problema deberias aceptarla para que la pregunta no quede pendiente eternamente. Mírate este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) para aprender a aceptar respuestas, gracias. De paso haz el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona este sitio.